# How to download Grub2 for Mac installation

Tags: grub2, partitioning, mac

So I've decided to play around with my newish MacBook Pro by adding an Ubuntu partition.  I also intend to eventually install Windows 10.  I went to the local Apple Genius bar, and had a kid there explain to me the process to download and install Ubuntu.  Unfortunately, I cannot for anything figure out how to download and install Grub2.  Nowhere can I find a download option.  I'm getting frustrated and confused.  I'm hoping that someone here who has installed Ubuntu on a Mac can give me some help.  Thanks, guys!

Comment: GRUB installs with Ubuntu. It's the bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download GRUB, because it's part of Ubuntu. (Not really, but it'll work for this case.)

If you install Ubuntu, you'll be installing GRUB too. Ubuntu takes care of that for you.

Comment: From what the Apple guy told me, that depends on which version of Mac OS I'm using.  Don't know if he was correct about that.  But if it is important, I am running Yosemite.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why you asked a Mac "expert" about installing Ubuntu. I doubt they would really know anything, and even if they did, they'd probably want you to break your Mac so they could charge you to replace it :p. Your Mac OS version should not matter, unless Apple's "fixed" something I don't know about.

Comment: I figured someone at the store would know, and I knew how to get to the store, and I didn't feel like learning how to contact Ubuntu.  From what the guy told me, most Apple "geniuses" don't know much about Ubuntu or installing it.  So the qualification to be a genius isn't very high ...

I'll try your suggestion in a minute or so and let you know if you helped me or are responsible for destroying my laptop :p

Comment: They are trained Mac geniuses. Apple isn't going to waste its resources training people to know about a competing free OS. Besides, we (and the rest of the internet) have tons of guides for installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, so I tried it.  I burned Ubuntu to a disk successfully.  Once I tried restarting the computer with the DVD in, the MacBook started like normal.  Then it told me the disk was unreadable.  Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: @BrianHicks how'd you burn it? Did you follow the instructions on the Ubuntu website?

Comment: Sorry I'm just now getting back to you.  I've been distracted.  I followed the instructions given to me by the Genius Bar kid.

Comment: @BrianHicks go to the website. Follow the instructions there.